# Is there any good way to pass in bytecode directly to sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a tool that allows Python developers to write pythonic code to interact with a sqlite3 database, similar to sqlalchemy but without the "translation" phase. If I can generate a sqlite3 prepared statement, how can I directly pass it to the evaluation system?

As a rough example, here's how I roughly view a user being able to interact with my tool:

```
myTable = Table("field1", "field2", "field3")
mytable.insert("foo", "bar", "baz")
select = mytable.select("field1")
---------------
print(select)
>>> ["foo"]
```

Comment: Doesn't Python ship with an SQLite3 library that lets them "write pythonic code"?

Comment: You're right it does, but it still requires you to write your sql statements out. I was thinking of creating an abstraction that, very roughly, allows the user to create python objects that represent SQL objects within sqlite3 like the following:

mytable = Table("field1", "field2", "field3"); 
  

mytable.insert("foo", "bar", "baz"); 

  
select = mytable.select("field1");

Comment: That seems like throwing away much of the power of SQL for little gain. Also, I fail to see how prepared statements and bytecode would help here, unless your plan is to bypass the SQL compiler itself. Which... why are you using SQLite if you don't want to use SQL?

Comment: And if bypassing SQL is what you want, you can just have `mytable` store the table name, and have `.insert` and `.select` manufacture the SQL commands instead of SQLite's bytecode. But again, if you're not using SQL's expressive power in queries, it seems like you want a NoSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no (public) API in SQLite3 that allows you to execute pre-built SQLite bytecode. The bytecode for an SQL statement can be viewed with the `EXPLAIN` SQL command, but this is meant for debugging and learning purposes, not for what you're trying to do.

And for most purposes, you shouldn't need this. If you feel that the time spent compiling a prepared statement will be a burden, `sqlite3_stmt` objects can be stored for the lifetime of the `sqlite3` database connection it was created with. Prepared statements that have been executed can be [reset](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html), allowing them to be executed again. So as long as the database connection exists, you can compile the statement once and use it as many times as you need to.

But that's about it. There is no mechanism to persist a prepared statement beyond the lifespan of the `sqlite3` connection. You can't extract the bytecode by any public API, and you can't use some bytecode you've obtained to reconstitute a prepared statement.

If you want persistence beyond the connection, then you need to store the SQL statement *text* in whatever place you want to be persistent, and then simply recompile the prepared statement when you reconnect to the database. That one recompilation (or many depending on how many you store) shouldn't be a particular burden, depending on the life span of your application.